# Как реализовать в виде класса позицию товара интернет магазина?

Tags: java, объекты

Суть задания:
[image: Требования к сущностям интернет магазина]

То ли задание криво сформулировано, то ли я что-то не понимаю.
Какие поля должны быть у данных классов?

Вызывает затруднение тот момент, что разные категории могут иметь разное количество атрибутов и значения этих атрибутов могу быть различных типов (строковый, числовые). Была идея сделать так

```
class Category {
private String name;
private HashMap<String, String> attributes;
.....
}
```

Но мне кажется возникнут сложности при фильтрации по атрибутам

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Создайте абстрактную позицию (abstract class AbstractPosition)  с полями: цена(вероятно float), количество (вероятно int) и статус (по всей видимости ENUM). И классы категорий, например стол: class Table с полями глубина, ширина и высота (единицы смотрите по обстоятельствам). Для табурета будут свои параметры, для дивана свои. Далее создайте классы конкретных позиций наследующих AbstractPosition, например для стола class TablePosition extends AbstractPosition с полем позиции в данном случае Table table;

Теперь у класса TablePosition есть стол и цена, количество и статус из суперкласса.